# jQuery.datePicker -calculate days

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hy!

I am using jquery.datePicker example from Kelvin Luck.
(http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html)

How can I calculate the number of days between Date1 and Date2 ?

tks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
function returnNumberOfDaysBetweenTwoDates(input1, input2) {
    var date1 = new Date(input1.value);
    var date2 = new Date(input2.value);

    var minutes = 1000*60;
    var hours = minutes*60;
    var days = hours*24;

    var diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());

    return round(diff / days);
}
```

Comment: return Math.round(diff / days);

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget the function name Math.:

```
return Math.round(diff / days);
```